# Changes NIVO slider Sliding effect

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with sliding effect of NIVO SLIDER.Now its overlapping images one after another from  left to right.But i want to shift the images from left to right instead of 
overlapping like easy slider.Is it  possible?Url is here http://www.markupxpert.com/nivo/

Comment: see this [custom-transitions](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/support/advanced-tutorials/setting-custom-transitions-per-slide/) and  [doc here](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/support/jquery-plugin-usage/)

Comment: Sorry friend,I used this but not working,Its also overlapping.I just need image sliding like http://cssglobe.com/lab/easyslider/01.html

Comment: @paul: It looks like the effect you are after is not present. Please see the docs - [List of effect parameters](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/support/jquery-plugin-usage/) at the bottom of the screen for available effects.

Comment: Yes Buddy,Its not present in the list.Its only possible by customizing the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("#slider").nivoSlider({
      effect: 'slideInLeft'
    });
});
```